# Illustrator is cropping exported icons despite artboard being Fit to Selected Art

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, artboard

I'm trying to export certain graphics from an Illustrator file. I'm selecting the object, fitting the artboard to the selected artwork, and saving for web & devices, PNG-24 format. When I look at the art in Illustrator, it is properly capturing the artwork, but when I look at the outputted file, I am losing a few pixels on the right and bottom sides of the image. Take the included image as an example, you can see it's not a perfect circle-- the top and left sides look correct, but the right and bottom sides come to too much of a flat part. Nothing is obscuring the art in Illustrator, and I can't figure out what is causing this. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

[image]

Comment: did you try to expand the object?

Comment: How are you fitting the artboard? by double-clicking?

Answer (score 1):

If, 'Use artboards' on export is unchecked...
I think problem is in fractional size of artwork.

While export, artboard size ain't matter, AI automatically fit the size of exported image to visible area. But this fit ain't precise, it may clip fraction of a unit and then extend it with ppi.

To avoid that, turn document units to pixels and measure Your symbol, decimal part should be close to 0.

You may also look at this question: [Illustrator CC: align new objects to pixel grid - TURN OFF!](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27810/illustrator-cc-align-new-objects-to-pixel-grid-turn-off)

If, 'Use artboards' on export is enabled, the problem is in size of artboard.

Answer (score 1):

As S-ed says, it can be an issue of placing.. you can turn on pixel preview Ctrl+Alt+Y to check how exactly you art is placed on artboard in pixel mode instead vector.

Comment: I did this: pressed CTRL-Y and deleted the few stray anchors which could be found outside of the artboard ("debris" remaining from previous deleted work). Then pressed CTRL-Y again. That fixed the problem. Your tip was relly useful.