# Illustrator doesn't respect coordinates

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to draw a simple line in Illustrator starting from an anchor, but it just won't work. Illustrator offset the end result for no apparent reason.

In this figure you see that the new line is not aligning with the end anchor. I draw the line vertically and the offset happens. I checked the settings and I have Smart Guides turned on, both snap to grid and snap to point are turned off. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Does [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/27810/52050) help?

Comment: Yeah that solved! But why is Illustrator behaving this way? Certainly I have pressed something and this pixel grid got activated. Can you add an answer so I mark as solved?

Comment: [This answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/66193/52050) shows how to turn it off for new documents.

Comment: if you choose a one of the rgb preset files its activated by default.