# Illustrator - Artboard misaligned everytime after saving

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

[image]

Refering to the picture above, wonder why the Artboard always misaligned by 0.5 for both X and Y axis after I saved it. Even after I align it back to 0, click save, the next time I opened the file it will still misaligned itself.

Comment: Try this answer. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27810/illustrator-cc-align-new-objects-to-pixel-grid-turn-off

Comment: Not able to solve. I find by saving it in AI format solved the problem. Saving in SVG mode will have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your presets re: web, print, etc. Should be snapping to the coordinates you input, but I've found copying my work into a new AI file helps with hiccups like these.