# How to make an irregular blended circle effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, effects, path-effects

[image]

I am trying to create an effect like this one in Illustrator, but I haven't been able to achieve a great result. I would really appreciate a little help, even if it is just the name of the effect. Also, if it is easier in another tool like photoshop, please let me know.

I have mostly tried a combination of the blend and warp tools. I haven't had any other ideas, or any luck googling.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/80938/how-to-create-a-line-graph-around-a-circle or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/103743/blending-two-lines-in-illustrator-gives-me-holes

Comment: Hey Scott! 1) Thank you for the links, I will study them thoroughly. 2) How did you locate these possible duplicates this fast? I'd love to know as I might be able to locate older questions easier that way.

Comment: `:)` I kind of know the technique so I have a better idea about search words, that's all. I know it's a blend of lines.. so.. that makes search results far more relevant. Your image would probably use a bit of both of those duplicates.

Comment: That's great, I guess I have to spend a little more time on learning how things are called. Again, thank you for the quick response, I will study the posts thoroughly and I'll try again to make the effect above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a gradient square background, draw an irregular closed shape with no fill and a thin stroke. My shape has a small feather effect.

[image]

Double click on the Rotate Tool > 1º > Copy

[image]

Duplicate until getting the first wheel > select all the vectors and group them.

[image]

Add another wheel group, the image is just a rotated duplication

[image]

Create a second similar shape but thicker, on the image has an outer glow effect the same color as the stroke.

[image]

Make the same duplicating process but less repetitions

[image]

Make three aleatory rotate/duplicate of the thick wheel, select all the wheels and reduce the opacity.

[image: Final]

Comment: Nice technique! For the rotations, you can use a Transform effect and save a lot of time :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I am going to use this and maybe try to combine it with a little blend tool too.