# How to generate wave line patterns in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, line-art

I have tried using the blend tool and the envelope warp tool. but I don't think you are able to make the twisting line pattern line the first one below.

Any suggestions ?

[image: Pattern Example 1]

[image: Pattern example 2]

Comment: You can do both of these with blend, yes!

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer: [How to make an irregular blended circle effect?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/109259/120647)

[image]

Comment: There's no repeat the same explanation in a new answer when there's already a duplicate question.