# Please help me recreate these vector waves

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to create the first image:

[image]
These are my results:
[image]

[image]

I am using Illustrator and the blend tool.

1. How do I get that color difference?
2. that darker smudged outline?
3. How many lines have been created?
4. I want that depth, how can I achieve that? Mine looks like very lame...
5. Do you think they're using a reduced opacity mask behind the lines?

Comment: The depth is created by creating different sets of blends.

Comment: Hi Allydesign, [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/109259/120647) can help you

Comment: @WELZ It doesn't give the same effect as the original graphic...

Comment: @Danielillo how does that help me? I know how to create blends.

Comment: @WELZ and https://imgur.com/AbgP1P8

Comment: @Allydesign it can help you reading well the answer and checking there are more than blends.

Comment: @Allydesign - note that in the answer to which Danielillo linked they employ both outer glow and various opacity states to get a far more subtle and etheric effect - the images you've posted thus far do indeed get the blend tool use correct, but are missing the visual dynamics in both your inspiration image and in Danielillo's linked answer. I suggest you look at that answer more carefully. –

Comment: @GerardFalla Yes I agree that I am missing the visual dynamics. However it is not opacity states, it does not appear to be outer glow or feathering effects either.

Comment: @Danielillo Sure it could, but the tutorial doesnt help create the inspiration graphic

Comment: @Danielillo That is correct it does not contain blend. But it does not help me create the inspiration graphic. 
I want to recreate the look of the graphic. I do not want to create "etherial" or "some of the visual language" graphics.

Comment: @GerardFalla Your output looks alright, but I am looking for something with more depth and detail like the original graphic. 
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Danielillo How can you determine that I have gotten an acceptable answer?

Comment: @Danielillo I'm trying to get a particular effect, and it hasn't been explained by the tutorials provided. Do you expect me to stop, follow the tutorial and work with something that is just "acceptable"

Comment: @Allydesign hi, I'm one of the moderators here. Above you wrote a comment to Gerard. Could you please instead put that comment on his answer. He will get notified if you put it on his answer and able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like this has some of the visual language you are looking for... and this one was created using ***not*** blends, but transform effects applied in Appearance Palette, and feather, outer glow and opacity for the softening

[image]

And this one's intentionally much closer to your inspiration example, as I threw it together super-fast *just* for this question... and these ***are*** blends, using outer glow, feather and opacity states to control the edge conditions.

[image]

And here's the final output as a png:

[image]