# How do I create this mesh type gradient effect in illustrator? (see image)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, illustrator-effects

[image: Vector typography I'd like to create]

This is the type of thing I'd like to create in illustrator, I've been playing around with meshes and can't seem to be able to do it. I'can distort the shape using the envelope mesh tool (screenshot attached) but I almost need to be able to convert into separate shapes unless there's a better way of doing it? Can someone give me some pointers on how to do it? Many thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDmqk.png)

[image: my effort]

[image: Done!]

Comment: [This answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/109259/120647) can help.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Essentially, don't write a generic title "How do I do this?", instead make it descriptive (for example "how to create this distorted mesh lines texture?"). It makes it easier for people to find and answer your question. Also show us some effort, post some of your own results so we can help you with that instead of asking for a full tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Comment: Thank you Danielillo, I've had a very quick go at what you suggested, but I'm not sure doing it this way how I would be able to create the uniform 'ripple' in individual sections? (attached screenshot of what I've done)

Comment: Maybe you should try another way to do your illustration different than gradient mesh. If you read the suggested answer carefully, you can get exactly the result of your question in a few steps.

Comment: Thanks Danielillo, with a bit of experimentation, I've managed to do it, I've uploaded the final result above, thanks for your help!