# How to prevent anchor points from moving automatically?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool, anchor-point

I am trying to do isometric pixel art on Illustrator. To this end, I am using a hex grid to draw simple cubes using the pen tool (as described in [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/WdIM3nMCQ2s?t=5m12s)). However, the anchor points tend to move by themselves. The result is : my cube is not a cube.

Details:

Here I put my first anchor point :

[image: Putting the first anchor point]

When I add the second one, the line moves down :

[image: The anchor point moves]

And this is the shape I get in the end :

[image: And this is the shape I get in the end]

Comment: Do you have Align to Pixel Grid switched on? If so, read this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27810/illustrator-cc-turn-off-align-objects-to-pixel-grid

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you so much, it was indeed a pixel grid alignment problem. So I selected everything, deactivated pixel grid alignment + deactivated the align new objects to pixel grid option. I wonder why such an option is activated by default, at the beginning I thought it was coming from the pen tool...

Comment: @TracerTong - if you create a new document from the Web document presets, the align to pixel grid option is activated by default.  If you choose a print document, it's not.