# How to create specific spiral/swirl effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

Looking for tutorial on how to create the 'spiral' effect used for the lions mane in the picture of the right. I've tried using dashed line and then swirl feature but this makes the lines go from small to big in width and I'm looking for how to create them all a single length, as it if they were pen strokes

Here is the design but as you can see in the red circle some of the curves haven't 'curved' properly and are buckled, how do you get rid of this and make them all properly curved

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a fairly simple process.

1. Create a circle:

[image]

2. Add a line down the middle:

[image]

3. Apply a rotation to the line (I did 10, you can do a higher number for more spacing) and copy it a bunch of times (36*) until it fills the entire circle:

[image]

4. Use the Twirl tool, hold it in the center (smart guides can be helpful) and just short press it until it looks right:

[image]

---

*360/10=36 you have to do your rotation degree divided by a full circle (360)

Comment: thanks really helpful, just one thing though, when I twirl the lines some are fine and some are slightly bent/skewed/buckled, how do I stop this?

Comment: @g.b341 I'm not sure what you mean... :/ sorry

Comment: Sorry my bad didn't explain well but attached a photo below to help

Comment: How'd you create the lines?

Comment: @g.b341 This likely happens if you don't hold the **twirl** brush directly on the center see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozj8l.png)

Comment: Using the tutorial you gave :), theyre all perfectly centred etc so idk whats happened

Comment: when you say 'hold' the brush how exactly do you mean?

Comment: *Place* the brush in the center of the circle

Answer (score 12):

This is essentially the same as WELZ's answer but using different tools; namely using effects which means you can adjust the parameters (number of lines, rotation angle etc.) without having to recreate the whole thing again.

1. Draw a single straight line...
2. Add a Transform effect (*Effect → Distort & Transform → Transform...*), set an appropriate number of copies and rotation angle:

   [image]
3. Add a Twist effect (*Effect → Distort & Transform → Twist...*) set to your desired angle:

   [image]

You can then modify both effects from the appearance panel if/when needed.

Note; if you get strange distortions in your lines when transforming objects you may be working at too small a scale, just work at a larger scale (then expand and shrink if you really need to). Also make sure you have [pixel snapping turned off](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27810/illustrator-cc-turn-off-align-objects-to-pixel-grid).

Comment: Somehow... I knew that *you* were gonna mention the Transform Effects. :-)

Comment: Of course. If I can do something non-destructively with some handy numerical inputs, then that's how I'll do it :)

Comment: I really need to use Effects more often...