# What feelings does my logo design invoke

Tags: logo

I am a software developer, setting up a new company called `mascot` to sell my services. I don't really have design skills, but needed to make me a logo, so came up with this luck waving cat to be my mascot logo. I am hoping it's friendly, fun and professional looking, but historically have been a bit off the mark on all counts, so wanted to check with the community what kind of reaction this logo invokes.

[image]

p.s. if this is not the right forum to ask this kind of question, can someone point me to the right place to do so?

update:

Thanks everyone for such awersome feedback - I tried to take it all on board, and had a go at a second iteration. No colours, more considered shape, more friendly, based on hand drawn sketch.

I am not sure how to get feedback from you guys on the iteration, is this question locked for comment now it is on hold? I would love to know what folk think about cat mark two, especially with regards to original criteria: fun, friendly, professional

[image]

update two:

Ok, how about a much more geometric approach to the original idea?

[image]

Comment: While critique questions **are** allowed, we have some requirements, have a look at them [here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/672/63979).  If you can rephrase the question to better fit those guidelines, it'd be awesome!

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to reach out in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot)

Comment: You really should *hire* a designer for  a logo, similar to how I'm sure you'd recommend people hire a software developer to create software.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. If you want honesty, then I'm afraid I don't think it works as a logo, and it doesn't look professional. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Lucian Please be kind :)

Comment: It honestly scares me. Literally, it's fearful.

Comment: So sorry mate... but it's ***not*** very good. The negative space is a jumble, the silhouette is no better, there's no proportioning system at play, there's no discernible composition, the colours really don't work (neither enough contrast for easy discrimination of elements nor a  harmonious colour palette) and it *really* doesn't work at a range of scales.
The *concept* is fine though - could rework it bearing all these points in mind. Use Fibbonaci spiral and/or golden ratios to recompose, pay attention to positive/negative space, either go *far* less rigid/more playful or geometricise it.

Comment: In many cultures seeing a black cat has been a bad omen. See it and something will happen - sooner or later, but it will happen.

Comment: Here are some non-judgmental logotype design criteria: It must look okay big (on the side of your delivery trucks) and tiny (for your website favicon) in addition to your business stationery. It should look good in colour or in monochrome (for when you want to use it economically.) It should work against white, black, colour, or pattern. If it's simple enough to describe as a basic geometric shape (oval, circle, square, triangle, etc.) and to draw, it has a better than average chance of being recalled.

Comment: After your edit with a second take: I'm sorry, but logo design is not something that you can learn from scratch. I don't want to sound jaded, but this still isn't very good and absolutely unfit as a logo. Either you need to put multiple tens (or maybe hundreds) of hours into learning logo design, or just get someone with some more experience. :(

Comment: Take a look at this similar post: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/107862/new-professional-branding-perceived-as-dull

Comment: Kind of all illogical if you don't explain *why it has to be a cat with one arm raised*. That, to me for software development makes zero sense without some sort of explanation. .

Comment: Please don't edit the question to ask more questions. Instead, open a new question to ask about a different logo. You already accepted an answer here.

Comment: @Luciano I asked a new question with iterated design here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/116079/does-this-logo-match-the-brief

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to try and be as kind as I can, please be aware that I do *not* wish to offend you or to seem as if I'm devaluing your efforts. It is *very* difficult to give design advice to non-designers if they feel overly emotionally attached to their artwork. I do *not* know you, your personality, your emotional attachment to that image, etc.

---

First....

Initial impression.... That, in my opinion, is *not* a "logo". It's a silhouette of a cat with some colors thrown in the middle. To me, it's a rather "creepy" looking cat. The uppercase "M" may even push the perception to a "creepy squirrel" due to the apparent buckteeth conveyed by the M.

Now, reduce the artwork, as all logos should work well at small sizes....

[image]

Comes across as a black squirrel to me. The ***last*** thing I'd perceive is "friendly" or "happy" .. rather more along the lines of "death squirrel" or "halloween squirrel".

I would suggest you *scrap this and start over*. There's no repair to be made to this image in order to get it to "logo" status, even remotely. The lack of clarity, detail, and definition are all so severe that the overall design is merely poor and unsalvageable.

---

Be aware that a logo is the #1 most important, all encompassing, image any business will *ever* use. In an **instant** it conveys a wealth of information to any potential clients/customers.

Choosing to "do it yourself" is really *not* always the best option if you are serious about your business. Design isn't "rocket science" and there are many, many things one may actually be in a position to complete themselves. However **logos** really can't be some image you've slapped together until you are happy. There are *a lot* of underlying connotations which are conveyed by a logo.

I would honestly suggest *hiring* a designer or finding a friend/colleague with some design skills to help. Not everyone who plays basketball can be Labron James, and, well, your design skills with respect to a "logo" need some help. If a business is to be successful, they need to treat branding the same as they'd treat any product or service they provide -- if the branding (logo) looks terrible, that is the *exact* impression you give prospective clients about your business.

Comment: The rodent-like teeth were the very first thing I saw.

Comment: To me it looks like a cat with its paw up on a window, it's face pressed close to the glass. I can't see it because the window is behind me, and I am watching TV on the sofa. It's staring into my soul. It's going to come inside.

Upvote for invention of term "death squirrel".

Comment: My cousin was killed by a roving pack of death squirrels in the 80s.  Vicious little things.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a designer myself, but we had to look quite deeply into this topic when we were looking for a logo for our own company. So here are my few inputs - happy for others to tell me where I'm wrong and where you think I'm wrong ;-)

A few general considerations first:

- print the logo in color / grayscale / black and white

  - turn your screen to grayscale while working to save some trees
- what are you going to use your logo for? what sizes?

  - favicon? business cards? banner? ...
- Does the logo reflect what you're doing? Is it representative of your company's vision / mission?

Now for your more detailed questions:

- Does it look friendly?

  - Honestly: not really. It seems to look at me in a mean way, cursing me...
  - I'm afraid it looks to me as if its right arm had been amputated
- Is it fun?

  - I think that depends on your cultural background. It may be fun in Asia, but I don't think it is in Europe.
- Does it look professional?

  - At least not to me - and I think the comments above seem to agree with that assessment. I'm not saying you need to go with a professional logo designer (even though you probably should), but if you want to do it yourself, you'll need to take the time to take feedback on multiple ideas, iteratively improve a few of the ideas and get a lot of feedback from friends and family along the way.
  - I think you could do a lot better with colors...

I hope this helps with the further evolution of your logo!

Best,
Chris

P.S. maybe start with sketching some ideas before you draw them on a computer.