# geometrical alignment based on grid

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, grids

simple issue or maybe really complex. another day of alignment issues that I can't wrap my head around.

Here's the stages (accompanied by images):

I have finalized one half of my logo design
[image]

I create a grid
[image]

I duplicate the object and flip it 180degrees horizontally, then I duplicate the grid

[image]

I align the central points of the object to the grid.

[image]

The object doesn't align to the other one.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Question is why?
Second question is can I even make it symmetrical?
Third question is do I need to and would a professional graphic designer of the likes of Massimo Vignelli have done this process in another way?

please help, brain is burning out and I really need your professional expertise.

Comment: Is `Align to Pixel Grid` on or off?

Comment: I assume you mean Snap to Grid and yes, it is off, I only have snap to point on.

Comment: No. I mean [`Align to Pixel Grid`](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27810/illustrator-cc-turn-off-align-objects-to-pixel-grid) <-- that's a link, click it -- Check the various answers, they've moved the feature since they implemented it and *where* it's located depends upon your version of Illustrator.

Comment: And I don't think Massimo was a computer user to any real degree. `:)` He'd have done it all by hand with triangles, French curves, and t-squares.

Comment: Illustrator doesn't let me use that option as it says contains art that cannot be aligned.

yeah, I know he didn't like them :(

Comment: Lock the guides (assuming your grid is made guides and not merely paths) then try again. (View > Guides > Lock Guides.)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/FTiC6hC.png
 this is the message I am getting

I've seen some late interviews with him where he uses a Mac, but I suppose it's just for email and browsing etc.

Comment: What is selected?

Comment: i get it when i select either of the two objects red/blue

Comment: Sorry. To difficult to suss out here. It would take specific file examination and that's kind of off topic. It is entirely possible to perfectly align things in Illustrator, but it can take some practice. And various application settings can make it more difficult or easier. *Which* of those settings are helpful or harmful depends upon construction and desired alignments. *How* you "duplicated and flipped" the object *might* matter... *what* you are selection *might* matter.... it basically all becomes a guessing game in this Q/A format.

Comment: so, how do I got on further about this?

Comment: I don't really know. You may be able to get further help in this site's chat if you can share the file and someone there is willing. But short of actually seeing the file it's an endless game of questions to find out specifics about construction and workflow. There's some setting somewhere causing misalignment (most often it's Align to Pixel Grid) and there's some reason you can't disable that feature - if it's even enabled to begin. I can only guess at what that may be, which could take a week to figure out in this format. But.. this is all merely my *opinion*. You may get answers still.

Comment: This really boils down to "*my car's making a funny noise... how do I fix it?*" --- The number of questions required to diagnose the problem, let alone offer possible resolutions, is astronomical. ---- Typically if you draw something... select it.. double click the Reflect Tool, set the 9-point origin as you want, and tick vertical and hit `Copy`... the result is a perfectly reflected copy of the artwork .. all still horizontally aligned. So, I think this is both a matter of workflow and possibly app settings to a degree.

Answer (score 2):

I think all those guides are confusing. Hard to tell what is snapping to what.

Try to keep it simple:

- Switch to *Outline* mode using <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>.
- Select the blue shape.
- Place the mouse cursor over one of the anchor points of the blue shape you know will have to snap to one of the anchor points in the red shape.
- Drag the shape until it snaps to the correct anchor point in the red shape.

[image]

As you can see even in this small size, the two circles don't fit exactly on top each other. Having merged them with other shapes have caused small deformations. So in order to avoid having some of the red circle sticking out beneath the blue circle, you probably have to remove the red circle somehow.

Comment: Excellent point about the deformation @Wolff- learn something new (almost) every day...